# Exporting file from google drive using googleapi in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api

I am using googleapi to export the file from a google drive. I have the following code in my export.js. When I run this file, even though i have given the mimeType it throws an error saying "The API returned an error: Error: Required parameter: mimeType"

```
var drive = google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: auth
});

var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./public/data/myfile.txt');
drive.files.export({
  fileId : fileID,
  mimeType : 'text/plain'
}, function(err, response) {
  if (err) {
  console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  return;
  }
  console.log('Received %d bytes', response.length);
  fs.writeFileSync(dest, response);
});
```

Comment: I have same problem, I have make an issue for it as well: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1098

Answer (score 2):

Ohai! Maintainer here.  When something like this happens, it's usually because there's some mismatch between the version of `googleapis` and `google-auth-library`.  As far as the code is concerned, we have a full working copy here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/export.js

Now - on what to do.  You need to make sure that a.) you are using the latest version of `googleapis`, and b.) you DO NOT have `google-auth-library` in your package.json.  Please try:

`$ npm uninstall --save google-auth-library
$ npm install --save googleapis@28`

Give that a shot and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: for me it was updating packages as Justin suggested and do some little changes to code.. more info here: https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1098, thank you @justin-beckwith for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try it this way and make sure your file matches the mimeType you are requesting and maybe you need to say that you are accepting binary data.

```
drive.files.export({
   fileId: 'asxKJod9s79', // A Google Doc pdf
   mimeType: 'application/pdf'},
   { encoding: null }, // Make sure we get the binary data
   function (err, buffer) {
       // ...
       // convert and write the file
    });
```

Note that the API returns a buffer object and you need to convert and write it to a file. [Refer this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838872/5617140)

Or you can use this  :

```
var fileId = '1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo';
var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/resume.pdf');
drive.files.export({
  fileId: fileId,
  mimeType: 'application/pdf'
})
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('Error during download', err);
    })
    .pipe(dest);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried these options as well. It didn't work for me. I get the same error "Error: Required parameter: mimeType"