# How to save returned protobuf object in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, protocol-buffers

In my code, a function is returning a protobuf object and I want to save it in a file xyz.pb.
When I am trying to save it using fs.writefilesync it is not saving it.

It is circular in nature. So, I tried to save it using circular-json module to confirm if there is anything inside it and it has data.

But, as I used circular-json in the first place it doesn't have the proper information(not properly formatted) and it is of no use.

How can I save this protobuf in a file using nodejs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to easily save protobuf object in a file.

Convert the protobuf object into buffer and then save it.

```
const protobuf = somefunction(); // returning protobuf object  
const buffer = protobuf.toBuffer();  

fs.writeFileSync("filename.pb", buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use streams [like mentioned in documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

as following

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const wstream = fs.createWriteStream('fileWithBufferInside');
// creates random Buffer of 100 bytes
const buffer = crypto.randomBytes(100);
wstream.write(buffer);
wstream.end();
```

or you can convert the buffer to JSON and save it in file as following:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
const wstream = fs.createWriteStream('myBinaryFile');
// creates random Buffer of 100 bytes
const buffer = crypto.randomBytes(100);
wstream.write(JSON.stringify(buffer));
wstream.end();
```

and if your application logic doesn't require to use sync nature you should not use `writeFileSync` due to it will block your code until it will end so be careful.
try instead using `writeFile` or Streams it's more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Protocol Buffers is to serialize strongly typed messages to binary format and back into messages. If you want to write a message from memory into a file, first serialize the message into binary and then write binary to a file.

[NodeJS Buffer docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

[NodeJS write binary buffer into a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34838872/824377)

[Protocol Buffers JavaScript SDK Docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/javascript-generated#message)

It should look something like this:

```
const buffer = messageInstance.serializeBinary()
fs.writeFile("filename.pb", buffer, "binary", callback)
```

Comment: It is throwing an error as "serializeBinary is not a function". Do I have to import any module or something for this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If using [protobufjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) module,  `finish()` method returns the binary array you would save.

```
const protoWriter = ProtoResource.encode(ProtoResource.fromObject(someJson));
fs.writeFileSync("./resources/output", protoWriter.finish());
```

Of course, `someJson` should comply with your `ProtoResource` message definition.